# Drupal - redirect url custom module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I a stupid problem but nothing is working.

Lets say i have a url : something/4
Then i use a function users_view to display output.
Menu for users_view

```
$items['users/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'your info',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'users_view',
    'access arguments' => array('view user'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Now i wont to get to it ...
I used another function to get to it via a link in main menu. I created a function user_created that gives me the user_id(this is just an example)

```
function users_menu (){
    $items=array();
    $items['users/'] = array(
            'title' => 'Your info',
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
            'access arguments' => array ('view user'),
            'page callback' => 'user_created',
        );

return $items;  
}

    function user_created(){
    global $user;
    $itemid=array();
    $temp_user= $user->uid;
        drupal_set_title('Your data');
        $result = db_query("SELECT user_id FROM {user_test} 
            WHERE current_user=:s", array(':s' => $temp_user));
         foreach($result as $item) {
         $itemid = $item->user_id;
          }

       REDIRECT to url users/$itemid
        }
```

I have used drupal drupal_goto , $form['redirect'] but nothing happens ...
The problem is it just says users/

Comment: I am not sure but why are you declaring $itemid as an array
$itemid=array();
then adding values to it in a loop like this?
$itemid = $item->user_id;
if you want to return 1 value maybe set it as 0 or NULL, if you want it as array set it $itemid[] = $item->user_id; and get it's values before redirecting.

also print the value of $itemid before redirecting using drupal_goto("users/" . $itemid);

just to make sure you have the right value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error, you have to fetch the result like this :

```
$result = db_query("SELECT user_id FROM {user_test} 
        WHERE current_user=:s", array(':s' => $temp_user));
$itemid = $result->fetchField();
drupal_goto('user/'.$itemid);
```